# Free unlimited geocoding for Italy?

Tags: data, geocoding, italy

I’m trying really hard to find a free geocoding solution that does not apply a throttle on the amount of requests - throttling the speed to 1 per second is still okay, but on the number not.

Does anyone know of such a service?

My attempts:

1. to find a simple API that can do this, the best I got was datasciencetoolbox, but the geocoding is on a street and not address level
2. running a docker container with nominatum - I’m trying it at the moment, but it doesn’t seem to work - it made my Mac Pro crash due to the amount of size the image took (I only focused on Italy) I’m trying this one more time, but I also suspect the geocoding won’t work very well even if I get it setup properly.

Does anyone know of a quality free solution - even if it will require a lot of work to set it up?

Comment: How many records do you need to geocode and what size of area/country?

Comment: 120k for addresses in Italy

Comment: I have successfully geocoded about 40k addresses using the free google maps API. you have to break the address tables into small amounts and request many API keys. its a lot of work but is doable. There is a QGIS plugin that you just need to enter your API key from google and it will geocode. its called MMQGIS

Comment: Unfortunately using many APIs from Google is not an option for me...

Answer (score 1):

You may have more luck with the Photon Geocoder described at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Photon . You can contact Komoot for the usage policy on their public instance.

Photon does provide a 53GB compressed search index of the whole world, see github for installation details. They don't mention uncompressed size of the index, though.

Answer (score -2):

there are some websites available which provide free of cost geocoding services(www.earthpoint.us/BatchConvert.aspx), but day limit is 2000 only. But if you need for educational/research purpose, then you can contact with admin, who can allow for more. I am using those websites for my research work. It provides street level address. I have checked it manually, 100% authentic.
apart from that, qgis has seperate toolbar extension for geocoding, activate it, and you can do geocoding as much number as you wish.

Comment: so can you provide some examples of these such websites

Comment: Yea unfortunately for me I need this for commercial purposes...

Comment: www.earthpoint.us/BatchConvert.aspx